# loading an html page using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Am new to Angular and seek your help. Is it possible to display/load an HTML page (i don't want redirection to a page) through a controller in AngularJS?

To elaborate: I have an application page that displays a list of items, say. Each item has a 'view' icon against it which when clicked should bring up a detailed view of the item.

```
    <ul class="list" data-ng-controller="check">
       <li>Item 1
           <em class="view"></em>
       </li>
       <li>Item 2
           <em class="view"></em>
       </li>
    </ul>

    myapp=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
    myapp.controller("check",['$scope',function($scope){
       $scope.somefunction = function(){how to ask it to load an html page i got ??};
    }]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look at [`ng-include`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude).

Comment: You can, also, use `ng-hide` & `ng-show`, as well as `ng-if` if angular 1.2.3

Comment: Am sorry, if this is a bit silly but ng-include, ng-hide etc would have to be placed on my html code isn't? Was wondering if i can have something done in $scope.somefunction() of my controller.

Answer (score 0):

ng-include is the correct way of achieving this. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

If you really don't want to do that you can fetch the page using $http and mark it as safe to render using $sce.

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>

myapp.controller("check",['$scope', '$http', '$sce',
   function ($scope, $http, $sce) {

      // Fetch contents using $http. 
      $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).success(function (contents) {
           $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(contents);  
      });
   }
]);
```